# SQLite Administrator concatenate results

Tags: sqlite, administrator

I have this table 
id   valor 
1     4 
1     3 
2     2 
3     3 
3     1

so, I need a consult that the answer be

id   valor 
1     4,3 
2     2 
3     3,1

I work with SQLite Administrator..please somebody knows how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,
       group_concat(valor) AS valor
FROM this_table
GROUP BY id
```